# local area IP Routing

Tags: networking, ip, local

I am using fiber internet service that company give me a device which assign me local ip like 192.168.0.1  ,2,3 and so on to my computer/ Laptop . but I want to change my local area ip like 172.15.15.1 etc. how to route my Ip

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well since the ip is assigned by the service provider they are probably using `DHCP` server to assign you ip. So you are getting those segment ip's, these are basically private `class c` ip address. In order to get different range of IP's you can put your intermediate router and configure it to provide private `class B` IP address.You might need a `cross cable` to connect both the routers.